# Segmentation Fault with Variable Array Sizes

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I'm receiving a segmentation fault when performing the following action. Say I define some grid size as follows.

```
#define DIM 512

int x = DIM;
int y = DIM;
```

Now I want to allocate some 2D array with these dimensions

```
complex double arr[x][y];
```

This produces a segmentation fault, where as this call

```
complex double arr[512][512];
```

runs smoothly. I'm sure it's something obvious that I'm missing here, but if someone has a step in the right direction I'd certainly be most obliged.

Comment: Are you doing it on the stack ?

Comment: Can you post a complete, minimal example that compiles and exhibits your problem along with any switches you pass to the compiler?

Comment: and certainly you should show us *where* the segfault occurs. It could be that your problem is just somewhere else, only showing here because you change some arbitrary condition that triggers your segfault.

Comment: Are `x=y=512` the actual dimensions with which you get a segfault?

Answer (score 2):

When you define an array statically:

```
complex double arr[512][512];
```

The compiler knows how large it will be, so it reserves memory appropriately.  However, When you declare an array variably,

```
complex double arr[x][y];
```

which you can only do this within a function, the compiler can't know how big it will be, so it can't reserve an appropriate space for it. The space will be allocated on the stack, and your stack evidently doesn't have the 4MB required for that array.

Ex:

```
double arr1[10240][10240];

int main() {
        double arr2[10240][10240];
        int i = 10240;
        int j = 10240;
        double arr3[i][j];
}
```

`arr3` causes a segfault when run, comment it out and it will work. `arr1` is put in the data section, `arr2` is put on the stack, but the stack is made large enough to hold it (which the compiler can do since it is of known size). `arr3`, however, is not of a fixed size, so the compiler can't reserve space for it. The program tries to allocate it on the stack, but its too big, so the allocation causes a segfault.

Comment: Actually, the example is too simple, at least for recent gcc's. You'd need to use the array to cause a segfault.

Comment: @DanielFischer It segfaulted on mine, I believe it's 4.4, I can check when I get back to work.

Comment: Could of course also be OS dependent. Ran here without problems with 4.5.1 on 64-bit linux when only allocating and not using. But regardless of whether the example segfaults on this or that setup, the principle is the important thing.